# subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector on index variable

Tags: c++, vector, subscript

I am receiving the error titled above, "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector", on all of my [i] instances, and can not seem to understand why. Another program I have done with vectors recently does not seem to have any noticeable difference and works fine. Does anyone see what I am missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int getData() {
    vector<int> weeklyScore(16, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        cout << "Enter quiz score (0-15) for week " << i+1 << " : " << endl;
        cin >> weeklyScore[i];

        if (weeklyScore[i] < 0 || weeklyScore[i] > 15) {
            cout << "Please enter a valid score (0-15): " << endl;
            i--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        cout << "Module "<< i+1 << ": " << weeklyScore[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int highScore() {
    auto weeklyScore = getData();
    int high = 0;
    int i;
    int high;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        if (weeklyScore[i] > high) {
            high = weeklyScore[i];
            ihigh = i;
        }

    cout << "The highest score is " << high << " in module "<< ihigh+1 << endl;
    return 0;
}

int lowScore() {
    auto weeklyScore = getData();
    int low = 16;
    int i;
    int ilow;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        if (weeklyScore[i] < low) {
            low = weeklyScore[i];
            ilow = i;
        }

    cout << "The lowest score is " << low << " in module "<< ilow+1 << endl;
    return 0;
}

int ave() {
    auto weeklyScore = getData();
    int i;
    int average;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        sum = sum + weeklyScore[i];

    average = sum / 16;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    highScore();
    lowScore();
    ave();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int getData(){
    ...
    return 0;
}

auto weeklyScore = getData();
```

For some reason you made `getData` return an `int` therefore the compiler determines that the `auto` in `auto weeklyScore = getData();` is also an `int`, not the vector you want it to be.

Since it seems that you want `getData` to return a vector of weekly scores you should change the function to do that.

```
vector<int> getData(){
    ...
    return weeklyScore;
}
```

This seems like a variation on the common misunderstanding that variables with the same name but in different functions have some connection to each other. This is not true. The variable `weeklyScore` in `getData` is a different variable to `weeklyScore` in `highScore`. There's no reason that these two different variables must have the same type or the same values. It is up to you to make that so (if that is what you want).

Another point, you call the function `getData` three times so this program is going to ask the user to input three sets of data. I doubt that is what you want. Instead you should call the function `getData` once in `main`. Save the scores in a variable in `main` and then pass that variable as a parameter to each of your three functions `highScore`, `lowScore`, and `ave`.

It also seems likely (to me) that the functions `highScore`, `lowScore`, and `ave` are supposed to return the values that they calculate (instead of just returning zero) and the returned values are supposed to be printed in `main`. But this is just my guess.

Understanding how function parameters and function return values work is an important topic when you are learning C++. Seems likely that this exercise is designed to teach you how that works.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, and I have tried what you mentioned. Issue now is, passing the weeklyScore called in main to the other functions does not work as intended. Does it being a vector require it to be done differently? For instance:                               int ave(weeklyScore){  // error: unknown type name 'weeklyScore'
    int i;
    int average;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        sum = sum + weeklyScore[i];
    
    average = sum/16;
    return average;
}

int main() {
    auto weeklyScore = getData();
    ave();

Comment: @Islandari No, being a vector makes no difference. The issue is that function parameters must be declared with a type, not just named, so like this `int ave(std::vector<int> weeklyScore){ ...` This is kind of the same issue again, just because `weeklyScore` is a vector in one function doesn't mean that the compiler is going to assume that it's a vector in a different function. You have to declare it as a vector (if that's what you want) in every function where it is used.

Comment: @Islandari Also in `main` you have to actually use the variable as a parameter when you call your three functions, again this isn't going to happen unless you write the code to make it happen. So like this `int main() { auto weeklyScore = getData(); ave(weeklyScore); ...`